# Getting p-value via nls in r

Tags: r, p-value

I'm a complete novice in R and I'm trying to do a non-linear least squares fit to some data. The following (SC4 and t are my data columns) seems to work:

```
fit = nls(SC4 ~ fin+(inc-fin)*exp(-t/T), data=asc4, start=c(fin=0.75,inc=0.55,T=150.0))
```

The "summary(fit)" command produces an output that doesn't include a p-value, which is ultimately, aside from the fitted parameters, what I'm trying to get. The parameters I get look sensible.

```
Formula: SC4 ~ fin + (inc - fin) * exp(-t/T) 

Parameters:
Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)


fin  0.73703    0.02065  35.683   <2e-16 ***
inc  0.55671    0.02206  25.236   <2e-16 ***
T   51.48446   21.25343   2.422   0.0224 *  

--- Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.04988 on 27 degrees of freedom
Number of iterations to convergence: 8
Achieved convergence tolerance: 4.114e-06
```

So is there any way to get a p-value? I'd be happy to use another command other than `nls` if that will do the job. In fact, I'd be happy to use `gnuplot` for example if there's some way to get a p-value from it (in fact `gnuplot` is what I normally use for graphics).

PS I'm looking for a p-value for the overall fit, rather than for individual coefficients.

Comment: Can you display your output? I find it strange that it is not already there.

Comment: You want a p-value for what exactly? What hypothesis are you testing?

Comment: @kolonel: I've added it to the quesiton now.

Comment: @MrFlick: These are two parameters that for phsyical reasons may, but cannot be assumed a priori, to be related. If they are related, the function I'm fitting is plausible for phsyical reasons - my hypothesis is that they are related and that this relationship can be reasonably described by this function.

Comment: @s_lohengrin I should be able to provide you with an answer in a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this in R is you have to use the `anova` function to compute the fitted values of your current model and then fit your model with less variables, and then use the function `anova(new_model,previous_model)`. The computed F-score will be closer to one if you cannot reject the null that the parameters for the variables you have removed are equal to zero. The `summary` function when doing the standard linear regression will usually do this for you automatically.

So for example this is how you would do it for the standard linear regression:

```
> x = rnorm(100)
> y=rnorm(100)

> reg = lm(y~x)
> summary(reg)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.3869 -0.6815 -0.1137  0.7431  2.5939 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept) -0.002802   0.105554  -0.027   0.9789  
x           -0.182983   0.104260  -1.755   0.0824 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.056 on 98 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.03047,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.02058 
F-statistic:  3.08 on 1 and 98 DF,  p-value: 0.08237
```

But then if you use `anova` you should get the same F-score:

```
> anova(reg)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: y
          Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)  
x          1   3.432  3.4318  3.0802 0.08237 .
Residuals 98 109.186  1.1141                  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: @MrFlick I would agree that there is more here on the interpretation of the statistical results than on programming, but one has to also  note the underlying use of the anova function.

Comment: You should give an example of a non-linear regression, which is what the OP is asking.